# Appropriate Application of Strategy Pattern

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

I'm writing a provisioning application that gets user add or remove requests, then based on the specified role of the user, goes and applies specified attributes and creates them in the system or goes and removes the user from specified roles in the system.

Would this be a good instance to use the Strategy Design Pattern or would another pattern work? Each user has the same operations executed on them, however each operations differs based on the context of the user.

Comment: Check command pattern. Maybe it will work better in your case.

Comment: Yes, Strategy sounds appropriate for capturing the differences between users.

Comment: Strategy is ideal. However, you would want to access the strategy via an interface and then inject the appropriate concrete based on your 'context'. Can you do this?

Comment: @DavidOsborne. Could you expand on what you were referring too?

Comment: So you would have your strategy interface with OperationX() and OperationY(), as you've said these are the same for each. Then you need two strategies that implement the interface but do OperationX() and OperationY() in a different way. So far, so good. However, the elegance of the solution is injecting the appropriate strategy so that the caller is oblivious to the actual strategy in play. Sometimes the criteria you need to use to choose the concrete strategy is not in the best place to make the selection and you end up with: if user.property == 1 then... else.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Hmmm.... Your way of reasoning touched my heart. Finer! Not sure, but you might be able to assist michael by making adjustments to the issues you have highlighted. That elegance you are talking about... I would love to see something where all kinds of callers are made oblivious to the strategy in play. Some of these assignment of responsibility issues you are talking about, I came across this Information Expert general pattern that says responsibility should be assigned to where information is. Would that help here to sort out the finer matters when Strategy pattern is applied?

Comment: @KamalWickamanayake Thanks for your comments. I'll have to look into the Information Expert pattern. I suppose my ultimate point, which I'm not sure I've articulated that well, is that the Strategy pattern is an excellent way to achieve the OCP and it's a shame when that achievement is negated with an If... ElseIf.

Comment: @DavidOsborne Information Expert is a very simple idea expressed in two three sentences. Just check this small portion of text: [Information Expert](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#Information_Expert). Accordingly, I was wondering what if dependency injection is done from inside the class. If strategies don't change often (as indicated by Michael), coding a method like setRole(role) to switch the strategy from inside and if needed invoke the same from constructor to initially set it appears to bring some elegance.

Comment: @DavidOsborne For a slow changing system (with new strategies), coding an If.. else to pick the strategy within the setRole(role) might not be an issue right? Or do you feel one would be compromizing too much in doing so? Do you recognize negatives? Some time ago I wrote a bit about these code level change needs here: [The end of dependency injection - who creates the dependencies?](http://www.deadschool.com/article/end-dependency-injection-who-creates-dependencies)

Comment: @DavidOsborne To be clear about the above mentioned setRole(role), may be it's better to be something like setRole(roleName) or setRole(roleId) within the User class that sets the corresponding role property of a User object and also switches the Role strategy used by the User object.

Answer (score 0):

I think Strategy pattern is feasible.

and if the operations could be classified and mixed for different types/groups of users, you might want to try decorator pattern too: literally you might want to accumulate a few operations into one while identifying user roles, something like:

Role 1 - operation 1

Role 2 - operation 2

Role 3 - operation 3

A user has role 1 and 3, then he should have operation 1 and 3 integrated into one operation.

Comment: Fortunately users don't have more than one role so I don't think I'm going to have to utilize tthe decorator pattern. Thanks for bringing it up though!